# PIE.htc - background disappears, but border-radius still not applied

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners, css3pie

Border-radius works for all browser except IE (I test it with IE8). The solution is to put `behavior:url(PIE.htc);` into the css class. Looks like the path `behavior:url(PIE.htc);` is correct, because:

1) PIE.htc is in the root folder and

2) the background disappears if I use `behavior:url(PIE.htc);`
and

3) the background appears again if I use `behavior:url(/any/other/wrong/path/to/PIE.htc);`

So, I believe `behavior:url(PIE.htc);` is used properly. 
Unfortunately,

```
.superborder
{
border:5px solid red;
//here are a couple of strings for radius settings that are work for other browsers
behavior:url(/sdf/PIE.htc);
}
```

removes the background in IE but the borders are still not rounded in IE.
I've read PIE FAQ, played with `position:relative; z-index and zoom.` all together and separately. Nothing helps. Does anybody know why?

**Added:**
I have found the problem but don't know the solution. 
The problem is this css:

```
#page-content{
 visibility  : hidden;
}
```

where `#page-content` contains the whole page.
It is hidden (as you see above) until

```
$(window).bind("load", function ()
{
    /*jumping fonts fix*/
    $('#page-content').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

So when the page is loaded, it becomes visible.
The reason I make it hidden until loaded because one of browsers loads the page although special fonts are not loaded yet. That's a good solution so the page doesn't jump until it is fully loaded.
Unfortunately, now I have to choose between these two fixes. How to combine them both - rounded corners for IE and font jump fixer?
Thanks a lot.

P.S. The font jump fixer above is my modification of [Using jQuery to know when @font-face fonts are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383226/using-jquery-to-know-when-font-face-fonts-are-loaded)