# Custom font and elements with 'width: auto'

Tags: css, webfonts

I am using the well known 'Open Sans' font family in my current project, and I'm facing the following problem.

I have buttons and other elements with `width: auto`, so when loading the page these elements will have a width calculated by the browser until the 'Open Sans' font is actually loaded from Google Fonts, then their size is recalculated, creating an annoying effect.

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/IkifUhUL/1 (refresh the page multiple times to see it in action).

Is there a workaround for this problem without specifying a width for these elements?

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4383536/3067042) out, looks pretty similar to what you want

Comment: Thanks. Taking a look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Google Web Font loader API for this. https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Basically this would allow you to hide the text until the font has been loaded and then you can show your text on load.

Something along the lines of

```
WebFontConfig = {
   loading: function() { // While waiting to load code here },
   fontactive: function(familyname, fvd) { // Once loaded code here }
}
```