# How to wait for page to load befor Reveal.js starts

Tags: javascript, github-pages, reveal.js

I have a short reveal.js presentation hosted [here](http://anbasile.github.io/reveal_pickmeup/) on GitHub pages.

I want to wait for the page to fully load before auto-starting the presentation. If the connection is slow, awesomefonts don't get rendered in time, and the user can only see an empty block.

Is it possibile to wait some time before start?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute Javascript When Page Has Fully Loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/execute-javascript-when-page-has-fully-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after a minute of browsing your code, I noticed that you probably need an onload block in your script before initializing Reveal.js. Try putting the

```
Reveal.initialize({
      controls: false,
      progress: true,
      history: true,
      center: true,
      autoSlide: 2200,
      transition: 'slide', // none/fade/slide/convex/concave/zoom
      // Optional reveal.js plugins
      dependencies: [
      { src: 'lib/js/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
      { src: 'plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
      { src: 'plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
      { src: 'plugin/highlight/highlight.js', async: true, callback: function() { hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); } },
      { src: 'plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true }
      ]
      });
```

Inside of:

```
object.onload=function(){myScript};
```

Hope this helps. The presentation looks great btw.

Comment: I tried with <body onload="function"> but it still get's loaded before awesomefonts are ready.

Comment: hmm... so it appears AwesomeFonts loads asynchronously. Can you link me to the api you're using?

Comment: Which api ? I am loading them via https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383226/using-jquery-to-know-when-font-face-fonts-are-loaded may be of consequence to you

Answer (score 0):

put your init code inside `window.onload()` function

if you need multiple things to be loaded asyncronously, just create a `myLoad()` function and a `objToBeLoaded` counter, then each time an obj has loaded, make it call `somethingHasLoad()` function that will check for that counter and eventually call `myLoad()`

Answer (score 0):

Reveal has a *ready* event, which fires when the content is loaded. Implementing the Reveal eventlistener function with the string 'ready' as the first argument and a function to be executed which holds your code should do the trick:

Reveal.addEventListener('ready', function () {
your code here
});