# Start JQuery Function After Font-Awesome Loads

Tags: jquery, webfonts

I'm creating a navigation menu based on:
https://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/

Everything works fine except for the line width and position for the active item.
Basically the width and position of the magic line is smaller than that of the active item.

I tried some fixes and concluded this is being caused by font-awesome icons because they take a couple of milliseconds to load in so it is causing the magic line to take the width without the icon loaded.
I tried using on window.load and it works fine, my problem is that the page might contain lots of images so I don't want the user to wait for the page to fully load before seeing the animation.

My question is this:
Is there a way to start the function after the font-awesome icons & google fonts are fully loaded and rendered?

Answer (score -3):

did you try  $(window).load?

```
  $(window).load(function() {
      //your functions
});
```

Comment: The OP says they used `window.load` in their question.

Comment: window.load works but I need something else because waiting for the whole page to load is not an option.

Comment: i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383226/using-jquery-to-know-when-font-face-fonts-are-loaded